# How to COUNTIF cells are years in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have several dates in let's say:

```
A1:A
```

with this syntax:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

and I would like to `COUNTIF` the cells that are years. I started with this formula, but that didn't work:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(YEAR(A1:A)))
```

Comment: Do you want to differentiate between `13/12/2013` and `2013`?

Comment: No, they should be counted as the same value. I mentioned it because someone might have a better solution for `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of only `yyyy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

### Formula

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(YEAR(A1:A15))))
```

### Explained

The `ARRAYFORMULA` around the `YEAR` formula makes it possible to accept a range. The `COUNTUNIQUE` counts the unique entries. It's simply a combination of `COUNT` and `UNIQUE`.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[COUNT UNIQUE YEARS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHRCcTBJUW5aTU9EclJza3YxejVsX3c&usp=sharing)**